# Updating java GUI as internal state of model changes

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, observer-pattern, observable

I have a problem with updating  the gui as internal state of the simulation model changes. Class simulator runs for the certain number of steps. Every step the internal state of the computer changes. Gui then gets notified and should repaint its graphical representation of the computer including text for the current state. Unfortunately with the classes detailed below the gui only updates the changes after the last step of simulation runs. I am using observer (computer) and observable (GUICanvas) pattern. What am I doing wrong, that the GUI does not repaint on intermediate steps of the simulation?

```
public class NwSim {


   public NwSim() {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame frame;
       Simulator simulator = new Simulator();    
       canvas = new GUICanvas();         //create gui  canvas, which paints guy computers
       canvas.setBackground(Color.white);
       contentPane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
   simulator.simulate();
   }
}

//represents the controller in the simulation
public class Simulator {
List<Computer> computers;
private int simulationSteps;

public Simulator()
    simulationSteps = 200;
              computers = new ArrayList<Computer>();


    public void simulate() {
        for(int step = 0; step < simulationSteps; step++) {
        for(Computer computer : computers) {
        computer.tick()
    }
    }
    }

    public Computer createComputer() {
    Computer computer = new Computer();
    computers.add(computer)
    }
}



public class Computer extends Observable {

    public void tick {
    ….. // update field state of the computer
        if (state.stateChanged()) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();    //notify observer- gui canvas that the state of computer has changed and it is time to repaint guiComputers 

        }
 }

 public string getState() {
return state;
 }
}

public class GUIComputer  {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int width;
 private int height;   
 private Image image;
 private Computer computer; 


 public GUIComputer(int x, int y, Computer computer component, Image image) {
     this.computer = computer;
     setX(x);
     setY(y);
     this.image = image;
     width = image.getWidth(null);
     height = image.getHeight(null);
 }


 @Override
 public void drawGuiComputer(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image, getX(), getY(), null);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawString(computer.getState().toString(), getX() + 20, getY()    // repaint the state for each guiComputer taken from Computer 
                + height + 10);
}
}

public class GUICanvas extends JPanel implements  Observer { 

//
private List<GUIComputer> guiComputers;

public GUICanvas(Simulator simulator)  {
     this.guiComputers = new ArrayList<GUIComputer>();
    // create guy computers using method createGuiComputer below , code omitted
}

public createGuiComputer(Transferable transferable, Point dropPoint, Computer computer)  {
 Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/" + imageName);
        Computer computer = simulator.createComputer();
                        GUIComputer guiComputer = new   GUIComputer(dropPoint.x, dropPoint.y, computer, image);
                         guiComputers.add(guiComputer);  
                         guiComputer.addObserver(this);

}

    @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;      
            if (!GuiComputers.isEmpty()) {
                    for(GUIComputer guiComputer : guiComputers) {
                // redraw guiComputer
                            guiComputer.drawGuiComputer(g);
                        }
            }
}

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
    for(final GUIComputer guiComputer : guiComputers) {
                 if(guiComputer.getComputer().equals(o)) {  
                  //if update requested by Computer object then update gui, redrawing all guiComputers
                  revalidate();
                  repaint();
              }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code indentation is a mess and your code example doesn't compile. That's the first problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely tying up the event dispatch thread or EDT with a long running time consuming bit of code that is running on the event thread:

```
public void simulate() {
    for(int step = 0; step < simulationSteps; step++) {
      for(Computer computer : computers) {
        computer.tick()
      }
    }
}
```

Try using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) or other background thread to solve this.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but the call to `simulate()` is in `main()`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: yes, you are right. There's much to the code though that has been left out, so I still suspect a concurrency in Swing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a `Thread.sleep()` somewhere in `tick()` or `simulate()` that you didn't show, the simulation ought to run almost instantly. All the calls to repaint() will then be coalesced into a single repaint.

**Edit:**

Here's a simple example where sporadic updates to `Observable`s on the `main()` thread are shown in a GUI observing them:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements Observer {
    Simulation simulation;

    Animation(Simulation simulation) {
        this.simulation = simulation;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        for(Blob blob : simulation.blobs) {
            blob.addObserver(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Blob blob = (Blob)o;
        repaint(blob.x - 12, blob.y - 12, 24, 24);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(Blob blob : simulation.blobs) {
            g.setColor(blob.color);
            g.fillOval(blob.x - 10, blob.y - 10, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simulation simulation = new Simulation();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Animation(simulation));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        simulation.simulate();
    }
}

class Simulation {
    List<Blob> blobs = new ArrayList();

    Simulation() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            blobs.add(new Blob());
        }
    }

    void simulate() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            for(Blob blob : blobs) {
                blob.tick();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Blob extends Observable {
    int x = (int)(Math.random() * 180 + 10);
    int y = (int)(Math.random() * 180 + 10);
    float hue = (float)Math.random();
    Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1, 1);

    void tick() {
        if(Math.random() < 0.05) {
            x += 4 * Math.random() - 2 + .5;
            y += 4 * Math.random() - 2 + .5;
            hue += Math.random() * .1 - .05;
            hue -= Math.floor(hue);

            color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1, 1);
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Russell and  Hovercraft Full Of Eels.                    Indeed the problem was caused by threads

Comment: I actually had Thread.sleep in my code before...but my simulate method was inside the action event for the button...therefore simulate() was running inside EDT, not the main thread, which explains why GUI has not been refreshing.... Adding 1 extra thread to run simulate() solved the problem, Thanks guys.